# Best approach for checking if user is authorised before dispatching another action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I have a front end application communicating with a database. Via front end you can modify the database, so I need to authorize users.

I setup authentication via google to enter the application, however I also want to check if user is logged in and authorised BEFORE every action that would involve database.

However I don't know what would be the best approach. My pseudocode would be something like:

```
handleSubmit = () =>{
    this.props.checkUser();
    this.props.dbAction();
}
```

However, obviously before checkUser resolves dbAction will fire. Settimeout also doesnt seem to do the trick. So how should I tackle this?

I'm using React with Redux on frontend and node.js + passport + mongoDB on backend.

If community finds that currently I am too vague I can provide some of my code that would revolve around this issue.

Comment: Read about json web tokens. https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec

Answer (score 0):

You should use [callbacks](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).
So your code should looks something like this:

```
checkIfUserIsAuthorized((response) => {
    if(response === 'authorized') {
        db.actions();
    } else {
        alert("You are unauthorized dude");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware which will wrap fetching and checking for authentication at the same time, so you won't need to check whether the user is authenticated or not every time you dispatch the action.

The closest example I found was this:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3001/api/'

function callApi(endpoint, authenticated) {

  let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null
  let config = {}

  if(authenticated) {
    if(token) {
      config = {
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }
      }
    }
    else {
      throw "No token saved!"
    }
  }

  return fetch(BASE_URL + endpoint, config)
    .then(response =>
      response.text().then(text => ({ text, response }))
    ).then(({ text, response }) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(text)
      }

      return text
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const CALL_API = Symbol('Call API')

export default store => next => action => {

  const callAPI = action[CALL_API]

  // So the middleware doesn't get applied to every single action
  if (typeof callAPI === 'undefined') {
    return next(action)
  }

  let { endpoint, types, authenticated } = callAPI

  const [ requestType, successType, errorType ] = types

  // Passing the authenticated boolean back in our data will let us distinguish between normal and secret quotes
  return callApi(endpoint, authenticated).then(
    response =>
      next({
        response,
        authenticated,
        type: successType
      }),
    error => next({
      error: error.message || 'There was an error.',
      type: errorType
    })
  )
}
```

Taken from here: https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Doing your auth checks on the frontend is pointless because a user can still call your server directly. You need to move this logic to the server ASAP.

Once the logic is on the server, you just need to chain your calls using promises, like

```
this.checkAuth()
    .then(this.doDbCall);
```